# Cross-linguistic study of distribution of number of verbal arguments

Tags: reference-request, verbs, cross-linguistic, linguistic-universals, valency

I think I remember reading once that cross linguistically, at least in "normal" spoken or written language, verbs almost never take more than ~4-5 obligatory arguments. This seems to be true in my native language, English. Does anyone know of a study showing that this (soft) constraint holds up cross-linguistically?

Comment: A related question is this one https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28569/is-there-a-limit-to-valency-transitivity — I don't consider it as a duplicate, because the other question does not ask for a study.

Comment: 3 is the normal maximum for arguments (transfer verbs like _give_ and _tell_ take an agent subject, a human receiver as indirect object, and also a direct object, the thing being transferred). There are also verbs like _elect_ or _name_ that take two direct objects and a subject. But most verbs take one or two.